# CSS text line issue

Tags: css, text, leaflet, tooltip, markers

I'm working my own map with leaflet.js.
When I typing the name of markers, there is some problem with text line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrgnS.png)

```
.leaflet-tooltip-small {
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black;
position: absolute;
padding: 6px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
color: white; 
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
pointer-events: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

For example, I want to make like this,

[MARKER ICON]
    Apple
    Apple
    Apple

But texts are always covering marker icon. What should I have to do to make texts are always bottom of marker icon?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't show your tooltip code - have you used the `offset` and `direction` options to control how the tooltip appears?

Comment: changing 'offset' was helpful to me. thank you peeebeee!

Answer (score 0):

use this css:

```
.leaflet-tooltip-small {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black, 0px 0px 2px black;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white; 
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50%;
    line-height: 13px;
}
```

And this code for the div Icon:

```
 var icon = L.divIcon({ className: '', html: '<span class="leaflet-tooltip-small">Apple Apple Apple</span>', iconSize: [null,null] });
```